# Updating Jira Plugin from Version 3 to Version 4, Replacing SearchParameter

Tags: plugins, jira

i am pretty new to Jira Development so please be patient
I should upgrade a Plugin that worked with Jira Version 3 to work with Jira Version 4

Most of the thins went pretty well, but now i am kind of stuck
The `SearchParameter` and the `ProjectParameter` Class are not available in the new Version and i dont exacly know how to replace them. its really just this few lines of code, where its needed

these Classes are outdated: `SearchParameter` and `ProjectParameter`

i looked in the jira doc buts its seems pretty complicated, you would do me a great favor if you could help me

```
SearchRequest sr = srs.getFilter(ctx, filterId);
...
SearchParameter param = sr.getParam(new ProjectParameter().getName());   
... 
List columns = columnLayout
                   .getVisibleColumnLayoutItems(user, 
                                param.getValues(), Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```

It would even Help if you could explain what the seccond Line intends 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you rewrite the plugin entirely, but I can try help you decipher what those quoted lines of code mean:

```
SearchRequest sr = srs.getFilter(ctx, filterId);
```

This line loads a saved `SearchRequest` with the corresponding `filterId`.

```
SearchParameter param = sr.getParam(new ProjectParameter().getName());
```

This line gets the Project search parameter that was saved in the `SearchRequest`. As you may know, `SearchRequest`s (or saved filters if you prefer) all you to save a search from JIRA with parameters defined. One possible parameter to define is a `ProjectParameter`. So if your search is "all issues in project X", then you would have a `SearchParameter` in your `SearchRequest` which is a `ProjectParameter` that knows to search for project X.

```
List columns = columnLayout
                   .getVisibleColumnLayoutItems(user, 
                            param.getValues(), Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```

This line retrieves the `ColumnLayoutItem`s which are visible to the specified `user`, for the specified projects of the `SearchRequest` (by extracting the value from the `ProjectParameter` of the `SearchRequest` as retrieved in line 2).

It's a bit unclear what this code is attempting to do without more context, but that's what those lines are doing anyway. You might find the API documentation useful:

- http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/3.13/
- http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/3.13/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/layout/column/ColumnLayout.html

Comment: hey tokes,
i have to thank you for your help, 
but furthermore i have to admit that i stopped working on this issue, becaus it was a bit too heavy for me
 
but anyway i REALLY appreciate your attempt, thanks and bye

Comment: For anyone coming late to this, I'd start with the notes on searching in https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Updating+JIRA+Plugins+for+JIRA+4.0